# adobe air: how to embed air runtime or simply distribute air applications?

Tags: air, adobe, flash-builder

My question is quite simple: I want to create an adobe AIR application for desktop (windows).

What if an user does not have AIR runtime installed ? Does newest version of AIR come now with EMBEDDED AIR runtime, so it works even for people that do not have AIR runtime installed ?

if not, what would be the simplest way to distribut my AIR application and make sure people that do not have air runtime will be able to run it ?

regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the Release of the AIR 3.0 SDK you are now able to distribute Air with your application using the [Captive Run Time](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air3-install-and-deployment-options.html)

This will allow a user to install and run your Air application without having the runtime already installed.

There are some downsides however. For mobile applications (and desktop alike) including the captive runtime can increase the package size by around 10MB. Also, for desktop applications, you will have to package the application natively (ie `.exe` or `.dmg`) but if the user doesn't have the runtime installed in the first place they can't run the `.air` file anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do this just recently and wanted to know exactly what you just asked.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/badge_for_air.html
That is what you need to know and will answer your question.

All you need to do then is deploy your .air file onto a server somewhere and point the javascript code to it.

HTH
Anthoni