# Publish AIR desktop application

Tags: flash, air, publish

This is what the users of my **desktop application** see when they launch my AIR installer.

What should I do?

[image: Do not install installer]

Comment: please explain your problem

Comment: @ShouryaSharma All those Xes and the questions marks in the popup. I want them to go away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Adobe Flash Pro** - If you couldn't use a trusted digital signature, you should embed adobe air with your published output. To do that, first deselect all check boxes of `profiles` (in Air Settings Windows) but `Extended Desktop`. Then select `Application with Runtime Embedded` for `Output as` setting.

[image]

**Adobe Flash Builder** - check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149296/adobe-air-how-to-embed-air-runtime-or-simply-distribute-air-applications).

Comment: What is the result output? Also I am working with flash builder.

Comment: @Babibu - For flash builder check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149296/adobe-air-how-to-embed-air-runtime-or-simply-distribute-air-applications

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a trusted digital signature, so you need to buy a certificate not to use a self signed one.
EDIT
There is no free certificates as far as I know, there are a few places where you can get one, so you need for digital signing application(not SSL) you can google for more information and search for a good offer(my employer buys this certificates so I do not know where or how much) also the certificates expire after a year or two.

Comment: Is there anything free?

Comment: yes there's one: www.certum.eu [for open-source projects]